# Numerically solving Lotka-Volterra ODE in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, numerical-methods, ode, runge-kutta

*Disclaimer: Cross-post on [Stack Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/numerical-solving-lotka-volterra-ode-in-r)*

**Aim:** I am trying to numerically solve a Lotka-Volterra ODE in R, using de `sde.sim()` function in the [sde package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sde/sde.pdf). I would like to use the `sde.sim()` function in order to eventually transform this system into an SDE. So initially, I started with an simple ODE system (Lotka Volterra model) without a noise term.

The [Lotka-Volterra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) ODE system:

[image: dxdt]

with initial values for x = 10 and y = 10.

The parameter values for alpha, beta, delta and gamma are 1.1, 0.4, 0.1 and 0.4 respectively (mimicking this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)).

**Attempt to solve problem:**

```
library(sde)
d <- expression((1.1 * x[0] - 0.4 * x[0] * x[1]), (0.1 * x[0] * x[1] - 0.4 * x[1]))
s <- expression(0, 0)
X <- sde.sim(X0=c(10,10), T = 10, drift=d, sigma=s) 
plot(X)
```

However, this does not seem to generate a nice cyclic behavior of the predator and prey population.

**Expected Output**

I used the `deSolve` package in R to generate the expected output.

```
library(deSolve)
alpha <-1.1
beta <- 0.4
gamma <- 0.1
delta <- 0.4

yini <- c(X = 10, Y = 10) 
Lot_Vol <- function (t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(y), {
    dX <- alpha * X - beta * X * Y 
    dY <- 0.1 * X * Y - 0.4 * Y
    list(c(dX, dY))
  }) }
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.01)
out   <- ode(y = yini, times = times, func = Lot_Vol, parms = NULL)
plot(y=out[, "X"], x = out[, "time"], type = 'l', col = "blue", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Animals (#)")
lines(y=out[, "Y"], x = out[, "time"], type = 'l', col = "red")
```

[image]

**Question**

I think something might be wrong the the drift function, however, I am not sure what. What is going wrong in the attempt to solve this system of ODEs in `sde.sim()`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0.1 * x[0] * x[1] - 0.4 * x[1]` for the second argument of `d <- expression(...)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry (sloppy mistake). I updated the code.

Comment: So does this solve the issue? If not please include your expected output (plot).

Comment: I included the expected output and code (using the `deSolve` package).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that not specifying a method takes the first in the list, and that all other non-specified parameters take default values, you are performing the Euler method with step size `h=0.1`.

As is known on a function that has convex concentric trajectories, the Euler method will produce an outward spiral. As a first order method, the error should grow to size about `T*h=10*0.1=1`. Or if one wants to take the more pessimistic estimate, the error has size `(exp(LT)-1)*h/L`, with `L=3` in some adapted norm this gives a scale of `3.5e11`.

---

Exploring the actual error `e(t)=c(t)*h` of the Euler method, one gets the following plots. Left are the errors of the components and right the trajectories for various step sizes in the Euler method. The error coefficient the function `c(t)` in the left plots is scaled down by the factor `(exp(L*t)-1)/L` to get comparable values over large time intervals, the value `L=0.06` gave best balance.

[image: error and solution plot]

One can see that the actual error

```
abs(e(t))<30*h*(exp(L*t)-1)/L
```

is in-between the linear and exponential error models, but closer to the linear one.

---

To reduce the error, you have to decrease the step size. In the call of `SDE.sim`,  this is achieved by setting the parameter `N=5000` or larger to get a step size `h=10/5000=0.002` so that you can hope to be correct in the first two digits with an error bound of `30*h*T=0.6`. In the SDE case you accumulate Gaussian noise of size `sqrt(h)` in every step, so that the truncation error of `O(h^2)` is a rather small perturbation of the random number.

Comment: I think I do not understand it completely. Does that mean that the Euler method is not suitable to solve a Lotka Volterra model? Or am I unknowingly omitting essential parameters/code?

Comment: AFAIK, the best you can expect from an SDE solver used as ODE solver is an explicit order 2 RK method. These are not very nice to conserved quantities, like the level of a first integral. To reduce the error, you have to decrease the step size. So yes, you need to give the correct parameters, at least additionally `N=5000` to get a step size `h=10/5000=0.002` so that you can hope to be correct in the first two digits. In the SDE case you accumulate noise of size `sqrt(h)` in every step, so that the truncation error is not that important.

Answer (score 0):

By solving Lotka-Volterra system of ODEs (initial value problem) with Runge-Kutta order 4 (RK4) method with the following code, we can achieve faster convergence and more accurate result with small time-step (`delat_t=0.01`) and obtain the desired plot:

```
Runge_Kutta_4_update <- function(xn, delta_t, f) {
  xn <- as.numeric(xn)
  k1 <- f(xn) * delta_t
  k2 <- f(xn + k1/2) * delta_t
  k3 <- f(xn + k2/2) * delta_t
  k4 <- f(xn + k3) * delta_t
  return (xn + 1/6 * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))
}

f <- function(v) {
  x <- v[1]
  y <- v[2]
  return (c(alpha * x - beta * x * y, delta * x * y - gamma * y))
}

solve_Lotka_Volterra <- function(v0, delta_t=0.01, niter=10000) {
  ts <- c(0)
  vs <- data.frame(prey=v0[1], predtor=v0[2])
  for (i in seq(2, niter)) {
    ts <- c(ts, ts[i-1] + delta_t)
    v <- Runge_Kutta_4_update(vs[i-1, ], delta_t, f)
    vs <- rbind(vs, data.frame(prey=v[1], predtor=v[2]))
  }
  vs['t'] <- ts
  return (vs)
}

alpha <- 1.1 
beta <- 0.4 
delta <- 0.1
gamma <- 0.4
solution_df <- solve_Lotka_Volterra(c(10,10))
library(tidyverse)
solution_df %>% gather('var', 'val', -t) %>% ggplot(aes(t, val, col=var)) + 
  geom_line(lwd=1) + theme_bw() + ggtitle('Solution with Runge-Kutta order-4')
```

[image]